# Converting a Pandas datetime index on a DataFrame object to *MultiIndex* with the levels "month" and "year"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Say I have a table of data with **monthly** `datetime` indices (the following code gives two years, january through december):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
N = 12*2
c = [datetime(1970 + i//12, (i%12)+1, 1) for i in range(N)]
d = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(N), index=c)
print(d)
```

What is the best way to convert the `DateTimeIndex` into a `MultiIndex` with the **separate levels** `month` and `year`? Perhaps there is a way to do this with `groupby`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct a `MultiIndex` object from the `year` and `month` and assign it to the data frame's index:

```
import pandas as pd
d.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([d.index.year, d.index.month])

d.index
# MultiIndex(levels=[[1970, 1971], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],
#            labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]])

d.head()

#                  0
#1970   1   0.657130
#       2   0.047241
#       3   0.984799
#       4   0.868508
#       5   0.678536
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.reset_index()['index'].\
                                    apply(lambda x:(x.year,x.month)))
```